# Properties and methods array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to write DOM viewer on JavaScript.

How I can get all properties and methods of some element?

When I used "attributes" array I am able to get only properties that has set before.

Thanks, Anton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var element = document.getElementById('someElement');
for (var item in element) {
    alert(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin, one additional question how can I get item values array?